# A subset of Context Free language is Context Free?

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

I'm stuck at solving this exercise, and I don't know where to begin:

A language B is Context Free; a language C is a subset of B: is C Context Free? Prove or disprove.

I've tryed using closure properties:

C = B - ( (A* - C) ∩ B ) [A* is the set of all words on the alphabet A]

and given that CF languages are not closed under complementation and intersection I would say that C is not forced to be CF. But I'm not sure this is a good prove.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you think it is not true, have you tried to find a counterexample?

Comment: Yes, I've tryed but I can find noone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a hint. A subset of a regular language is not necessarily regular: `a*b*` is regular, but `a^nb^n` is a subset of `a*b*` and is not regular. Can you think of a parallel for context-free languages?

Comment: So for example: B= {A^n B^m C^n | n,m >0}; A={A^n B^m C^n | n=m}. A is a subset of B, but it isn't CF.